# Why do I get error 34018 for keychain when side-loading an app?

Tags: ios, keychain, codesign, sideloading

I have tried to side-load YouTube, but the issue is in login. I get the web login page for Google, and login fine but afterwards I get the message inside app that I am using YouTube in signed-out mode. If I press the account settings page, I get the "Sign in" button.

The console keeps displaying this message:

```
YouTube(Module_Framework)[11300] <Notice>: Keychain Error: Unable to add new item: -34018
```

I am not making any modifications to app, and simply got a decrypted IPA (v13.32.7) to play with.

I have the following in my entitlements:

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
<string>6Gxxxxxxxx.com.xxxxx.ULYouTube</string>     
</array>

<key>get-task-allow</key>
<true/>

<key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
<array>
</array>

<key>com.apple.developer.default-data-protection</key>
<string>NSFileProtectionComplete</string>
```

Any help would be appreciated.